# Webpack not excluding node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack for a Node framework that I'm building (though I should probably use gulp, admittedly). When I include the EJS module, webpack includes it in the compiled source, even though I explicitly tell it to exclude the node_modules dir.

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    target: 'node',
    // ...
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
        // ...
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?{ "stage": 0, "optional": ["runtime"] }'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

As you can see, I have a test for JS files, and I tell it to exclude node_modules; why is it ignoring my exclude?

Comment: good job friend thank you

Answer (score 241, accepted):

From your config file, it seems like you're only excluding `node_modules` from being parsed with `babel-loader`, **but not** from being bundled.

In order to exclude `node_modules` and native node libraries from bundling, you need to:

1. Add `target: 'node'` to your `webpack.config.js`. This will define NodeJs as the environment in which the bundle should run. For webpack, it changes the chunk loading behavior, available external modules and generated code style (ie. uses `require()` for NodeJs) it uses during bundling.
2. Set the `externalPresets` of `node` to `true`. As of Webpack@5, This configuration will [exclude native node modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) (path, fs, etc.) from being bundled.
3. Use [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) in order to exclude other `node_modules`.

So your result config file should look like:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // use require() & use NodeJs CommonJS style
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    externalsPresets: {
        node: true // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc. 
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: Is there something similar on the browser? (i.e. target: 'browser')

Comment: I’m trying to understand what `exclude: /node_modules/` does. Could you elaborate? What could happen if we would leave it out?

Comment: It's a regex. if you leave it out, node_modules will be included

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it will exclude the `node_modules` dir from having the `babel-loader` run over it, but it will not exclude it from the bundle

Comment: I implemented this but got error that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'.

Comment: In other for this solution to work, don't forget to install the [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) library. `npm install webpack-node-externals --save-dev` @Ali

Comment: In my case " target:"node", was missing in the config section. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 24):

If you ran into this issue when using TypeScript, you may need to add `skipLibCheck: true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver

Answer (score 10):

Try use absolute path:

```
exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
```

Comment: can you show us how the project is structured? The file structure

Comment: Why do this?  `/node_modules/` will match any possible path in the node modules won't it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the solutions above didn't work for me in my TypeScript project, what worked was configuring webpack production and development mode options.

### Step 1

Install webpack merge (This allows you to have a [similar configuration](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#setup))

```js
npm install --save-dev webpack-merge
```

### Step 2.

Create `webpack.dev.js` and `webpack.prod.js` files in the same directory as your `webpack.config.js`.

```js
touch webpack.dev.js webpack.prod.js
```

### Step 3.

Paste this code inside your `webpack.dev.js` file:

```js
// webpack.dev.js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const config = require("./webpack.config.js");

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
});
```

- Paste the same code in the `webpack.prod.js` file but change the **mode** to `'production'` and delete the **devtool** key.

```js
// webpack.prod.js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const config = require("./webpack.config.js");

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: "production",
});
```

### Step 4.

Update your `package.json` file to use the new configuration files:

```js
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --watch --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
```

Now simply execute `npm run dev` to see your changes

With this solution, you don't need to run build for every change and **node_modules** is excluded from the compiler.

You can read more about this solution [webpack production mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me:

exclude: [/bower_components/, /node_modules/]

**module.loaders**

A array of automatically applied loaders.

Each item can have these properties:

test: A condition that must be met

exclude: A condition that must not be met

include: A condition that must be met

loader: A string of "!" separated loaders

loaders: A array of loaders as string

A condition can be a RegExp, an absolute path start, or an array of one of these combined with "and".

See [http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

Answer (score -7):

try this below solution:

```
exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better if you provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another (Alan) user already posted that solution 5 years ago. You should vote it up once you have enough reputation