# Angular2 component - Webpack producing large bundle

Tags: angular, webpack

I am in the process of developing a third party datepicker component for Angular (2+). Previously I have used Rollup for bundling however due to constant issues dealing with MomentJS imports I am looking to replace Rollup with Webpack. I have Webpack working however the file size difference is massive;

- **Rollup** - 32kb
- **Webpack** - 504kb

On looking into the generated Webpack bundle it seems that all dependencies are being bundled (Angular etc). How can I specify to Webpack that I only want to bundle my component's files and ignore vendor code?

For reference the two config files;

```
// rollup.config.js

export default {
  entry: 'dist/index.js',
  dest: 'dist/bundles/bundle.js',
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'umd',
  moduleName: 'ng.myModule',
  globals: {
    '@angular/core': 'ng.core',
    '@angular/core/testing': 'ng.core.testing',
    '@angular/common': 'ng-common',
    '@angular/forms': 'ng-forms',
    'rxjs/Observable': 'Rx',
    'rxjs/ReplaySubject': 'Rx',
    'rxjs/add/operator/map': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/pluck': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/first': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/merge': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/throw': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/of': 'Rx.Observable'
  }
}
```

-

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

const config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundles/bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      beautify: false,
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        negate_iife: false
      },
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (embarrassingly) I've just found the answer thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001237/webpack-not-excluding-node-modules)

Installed [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals), added to `externals: [nodeExternals()]` to `webpack.config.js` and re-ran the build, output resulted at 24kb (so even smaller than Rollup!).