# Webpack: include specific file instead of package.json specified?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack configuration:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test:    /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test:    /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:  'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test:    /\.elm$/,
        exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
        loader:  'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true',
          options: {debug: true, warn: true},
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],

    noParse: /\.elm$/,
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    stats: { colors: true },
  },

};
```

I have a few questions:

1. According to me the above config says that it should not be looking
   for js files in node_modules. However it is still bundling
   ./node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.es.js when I call require ("dexie"). (I am just doing this to experiment and understand webpack).
2. I would rather like to call dexie.js instead of dexie.es.js. How do
   I make this happen. I know I can set the  mainFields property.
   However how do I do this on a prelibrary basis instead of globally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your requirement fully, but an option is to set up aliases in the webpack resolve

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    ...
  },

  output: {
    ...
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
    ],

    noParse: /\.elm$/,
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      dixie: 'node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js'
    }
  },

  devServer: {
    ...
  },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

To your **first question** please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820388/2379376). It has already been answered.
No matter what you exclude in your loaders config, the file will be bundled unless you define it as external in your config.

To your **second question**, you can just require the other file with

```
require('dexie/dexie.js')
```

When you just write `require('dexie')`, webpack will look in your node_modules folder for a folder named 'dexie', read the package.json and resolve the file described by the module property. This is described [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#resolving-rules-in-webpack).

For more info, please read [the webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/). They are excellent.