# How to prevent webpack from bundling node_modules folder [ Webpack 4.40.2 ]

Tags: node.js, webpack

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I've tried  different variation and configs :

- target: "node"
- exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
- exclude: ["/node_modules"]

[image: Directory structure]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you ppreparing a library and don't want to have 3rd party libraries in your bundle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack not excluding node\_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001237/webpack-not-excluding-node-modules)

Comment: @lavor I usually use grunt, I'm new to webpack, so maybe I'm misunderstanding what webpack is actually bundling. When I look at my dist/bundle.js it looks like it is bundling  in a ton of modules with my custom source files.

Comment: If you are preparing final application, you need in bundle all dependencies that you are importing in your source files, so yes they will be there (you can optionally extract them in separate bundle with webpack application, but it is still necessary for runnig you app). But if you are preparing library that will be used in another applications, you need to specify 3rd party libraries as externals (e.g., see link in previous comment), hence your library will contain only your sources.